# document.getElementById returns null for unknown reason

Tags: javascript, html

The code is for a slider to switch images. When I run the page I get this error:

> Cannot set property 'onclick' of null.

HTML:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Image Slider</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sliderswag.css">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="imgslidescript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box">
    <img id="main" src="http://lmetar.com/oscar1.jpg">
    <img id="left" src="http://lmetar.com/left.png">
    <img id="right" src="http://lmetar.com/right.png">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 document.getElementById('left').onclick = slideChange;
document.getElementById('right').onclick = slideChange;
var slideNumber = 0;
function slideChange()
{
    slideNumber += 1;
    if (slideNumber > 3)
    {
        slideNumber = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('main').src = 'http://lmetar.com/oscar' + slideNumber + '.jpg';
    }
}
```

Comment: That probably means that your JS is being executed before the DOM loads. Either wrap the code in a DOM loaded callback, or move the position of the `<script>` element to the end of the `<body>` element.

Comment: place your `script` tag at the bottom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the best place to put <script> tags in HTML markup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

Answer (score 6):

Move your script to the end of your page. You're running JavaScript on elements that don't yet exist.

Or wrap the code you have in a [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) call which will execute the code after the window has loaded. Ex:

```
 window.onload = function () {
   document.getElementById('left').onclick = slideChange;
   document.getElementById('right').onclick = slideChange;
   var slideNumber = 0;

   function slideChange() {
     slideNumber += 1;
     if (slideNumber > 3) {
       slideNumber = 1;
     } else {
       document.getElementById('main').src = 'http://lmetar.com/oscar' + slideNumber + '.jpg';
     }
   }
 };
```

Comment: Consider adding an event listener attached to the document instead of a `window.onload`. See Druzion's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript is loading before you content, therefore it is trying to find elements that do not exists. You have 2 options:

1. Move your `<script>` tag to the end of your page
2. Use the following to wait until the page has loaded before you execute your script

Code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  // Your Code Here
});
```